# Rotating navigation elements - jquery, css3, html

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transforms

I have been doing an fancy rotating menu last few days with using transition effects and unfortunately I needed to use jQuery script for it.

Back to the point. I have developed advanced stage of menu and now struggling with navigation arrows. Moving with keyframes direction so from left to right is quite right (it's getting little messed after few clicks)

However if you click an right arrow for example three times each one by one and then click left arrow it's starting from original position instead where does it has been stopped.
I just ran out of ideas how to solve it in appropriate way.

I have prepared an example of my work. Most of elements are dropped due to keeping it much simple way

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Morrdo/u7d66oj5/3/)

NOTE - I am aware that I should use `-webkit-` but for this stage I am keeping it like this

I would greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: To coordinate the animation and avoid it to be "messed", disable the arrows until the animation is finish. When you click the arrows, the animations start using the CSS values as the start point.

Comment: @DIEGOCARRASCAL Thank you for your reply. Thats good point to disable an arrows until animation is not finished. I know that when i switch rotating side for example from right to left it will start over from startpoint but the question is how to prevent that and move from current position

Comment: Well, I have been trying to modify your code, but the name of the animation makes it static... try to create a "function" that do the animations of the element using parameters, that way it won't restart, but it will continue where you left before...